# Storing data in database vs within a class

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm building a PHP app using Laravel 4.2. The app allows a user to visit a website and submit a unique code. When the code is submitted, they are presented with a reward that they have earned. The rewards can vary from things like "10% off your next purchase", "A free t-shirt", "Free shipping on your next purchase", etc.

I have a `Code` model in my application which is the model for the unique code the user initially submits. So the first step in the application is to check the code they submitted, make sure it exists in the database, and then respond with a list of possible rewards they are eligible for.

My first thought is to have a `Reward` model and a `rewards` table to store the available rewards in a database, and then just present the relevant ones to the user after they submit their unique code.  Something like this in my template:

```
<ul> 
    @foreach($rewards as $reward) 
        <li>{{ $reward->name }}</li>
        <li>{{ $reward->value }}</li>
        <li>{{ $reward->redemption_instructions }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

However, I am now thinking it would actually be more convenient for me to have each reward set up as it's own class. That way I can build in as much custom functionality to each reward type as I need. So for example, every reward class would have a method called `display()`, which would output the necessary html to display the reward to the user. In that case, my templates would look something like this:

```
<ul> 
    @foreach($rewards as $reward) 
        <li>{{ $reward->display() }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to set things up so they function this way. I am planning to set up classes to store the information needed for each reward. For example, one might look like this:

```
class TenPercentOffNextOrderReward {
    private $name = '10% Off Your Next Order';

    private $description = 'Take 10% off your next order on our website!';

    public function createCoupon() {
        // create a coupon for this reward
    }
}

class FreeShirtReward {
    private $name = 'Free T-Shirt';

    private $description = 'Get a free t-shirt!';

    public function sendShirt() {
        // send tshirt to customer
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, each reward type will have different functionality. Is this the best way to handle this type of setup? Should my `rewards` table just store the different class names for all of the rewards? Do I even need a `rewards` table at all?

Comment: Try to avoid these opinion based questions; they're considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. That being said, I would use a single table/model for this, join the table to the code so one code can have many rewards.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, having a table containing the data for anything redundant (like name, description, etc) is better practice, because that also facilitates later being able to enter new rewards using a web interface down the line. Then the reward-specific display rules should be specified using either some server-side logic (like you do within your classes above) OR just using some sort of templating mechanism and referring to them by a template_id that you would store in your. In fact even the template_id could be stored along with a matching template in a lookup table in your database, making THAT editable in the future, too.

So not only would I leave it in a database, but if you want to customize your display templates, you might consider enhancing your database to accommodate that rather than paring it down.

Generally speaking, databases tables are good for storing multiple instances of something that has similar properties (like possible rewards), and classes are good for defining behaviors (how they display), so you're not going down the wrong path to consider using classes, but I'd just make sure to actually store the data about those rewards in a database and only handle their behavior in your programming code, not the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

If rewards may have its own business logic (like sending shirt) it will be better to use classes.

```
interface RewardInterface
{
    public function getName();

    public function getDescription();

    public function reward();
}

class NextOrderReward implements RewardInterface
{
    private $percent;

    public function __construct($percent = 10)
    {
        $this->percent = $percent;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->percent.'% Off Your Next Order';
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return 'Take '.$this->percent.'% off your next order on our website!';
    }

    public function reward()
    {
        // create coupon
    }
}

class FreeShirtReward implements RewardInterface
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Free T-Shirt';
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return 'Get a free t-shirt!';
    }

    public function reward()
    {
        // send tshirt to customer
    }
}
```

Usage.

```
$rewards = [new NextOrderReward(), new NextOrderReward(20), new FreeShirtReward()];

<ul> 
    @foreach($rewards as $reward) 
        <li>{{ $reward->getName() }} <span>{{ $reward->getDescription() }}</span></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Instantiating all `RewardInterface` classes at once. Of course, all constructors should have no params.

```
$rewards = [];
foreach (get_declared_classes() as $className) {
    if (in_array('RewardInterface', class_implements($className))) {
        $rewards[] = new $className();
    }
}
```

Note, if there are no specific business logic for rewards, using classes may be overengineering.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. What if a `Code` has only specific rewards associate to it? In that case, I need to programmatically access the rewards. So I would create a table that joins codes to rewards, and then my `Code` model will need a `getRewards()` method. In this case, shouldn't I store the related rewards class names in the database, so that I when I call `getRewards()`, I can loop through them and instantiate the appropriate objects?

Comment: I do not think storing class names in DB does make sense. DB should not know anything about your PHP code. I updated the answer to show instantiating all classes implemented given interface at once.